# How to create a 3D plot of a path from equations of motion in wxMaxima?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I have the following equations of motion of a point:

```
x(t):=r*cos(t^2)$
y(t):=r*sin(t^2)$
z(t):=b*t$
```

I already calculated the velocities and accelerations but now I would like to plot a path in 3D for this data:

```
r:5;
b:2;
```

It should look like a kind of spiral.

I tried various commands to create this 3D plot but none of them worked. All the examples of 3D plots in wxMaxima that I've found are surfaces while in this case, I want to create a curve. Is it possible in this software?

Here are two of the failed attempts:

```
wxplot3d([x(t), y(t), z(t)], [t, 0, 45]);
wxplot3d([parametric, x(t), y(t), z(t), [t, 0, 45]]);
```

**UPDATE:** The command below works but the plot is incorrect for some reason (I attached it as a picture). Is that because of the characteristics of these functions? Do I need some additional input?

```
wxdraw3d(parametric (x(t), y(t), z(t), t, 0, 45));
```

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I tried the following command:

```
wxdraw3d(nticks = 10, parametric (x(t), y(t), z(t), t, 0, 45));
```

and the plot looks better (only with `nticks=10`):

[image]

But it's still not what I would expect. Here's a reference plot from a Polish book describing MathCAD use in mechanics (so I can't utilize the code presented there directly):

[image]

Maybe the problem lies in the fact that the authors of this book use some tricks ("auxiliary variables scaling the argument of the function") to obtain the plot. But I assume that it's only necessary in MathCAD. I can be wrong though...

If you know how to define a range variable in Maxima, I can try to replicate the approach from the book in Maxima.

**UPDATE 3:** Here's what was done in the book to obtain that plot using MathCAD:

define auxiliary variables scaling the argument of the function:

```
M:=1000
K:=0,1.. 45
```

for which the time domain is given by:

```
t_k:=k*sqrt(π/M)
```

define the functions for plotting as:

```
X_k:=r*cos(((k^2)/M)*π)
Y_k:=r*sin(((k^2)/M)*π)
Z_k:=b*k
```

And here's my attempt to translate this to Maxima:

```
M:1000$
assume(k >= 0, k <= 45);
t_k:k*sqrt(%pi/M);
X_k(t_k):=r*cos(((k^2)/M)*%pi);
Y_k(t_k):=r*sin(((k^2)/M)*%pi);
Z_k(t_k):=b*k;
wxdraw3d(nticks = 10, parametric (X_k(t_k), Y_k(t_k), Z_k(t_k), t_k, 0, 45));
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
draw3d (parametric): non defined variable
```

That's likely because of the way `k` was defined. Can such a range variable be defined differently in Maxima?

Comment: Try `wxdraw3d (parametric (x(t), y(t), z(t), t, tmin, tmax))` i.e. `wxdraw3d` instead of `wxplot3d` -- `draw` is an add-on package which has some plotting functions which are different from the built-in stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `wxdraw3d(parametric (x(t), y(t), z(t), t, 0, 45));` and it works but the plot is incorrect for some reason. I will update my original question since I can't add images here.

Comment: Oh, I think the problem is that the number of points at which the function is evaluated is fixed for `draw3d(parametric(...))`. Try `wxdraw3d (nticks = nnn, parametric (...))` where nnn = 100 or 1000 or something. I think `parametric` should use adaptive plotting, so that's a bit of a shortcoming; I'll create a feature request ticket about that.

Comment: Thank you. I used this command but the plot still doesn't look right, unfortunately. When I increase the number of nticks, it becomes more messy. With 10 it's not that bad but still doesn't resemble the reference plot from a book meant for MathCAD users. I updated my original question again to include these plots. I will appreciate any further help.

Comment: It looks to me like draw3d is working okay and the unexpected behavior comes from the argument t^2 in sin and cos. Note that if t goes from 0 to 45, then t^2 goes from 0 to about 2000, i.e., many, many full periods of sin and cos. I think that's the mess you are seeing. When the upper limit for t is much smaller, I get a nice picture, e.g.: `draw3d (nticks=nnn,  parametric (x(t), y(t), z(t), t, 0, t1)), nnn=1000, t1=sqrt(10*%pi);` It's not exactly the same as the figure  you showed, so I wonder if they were working with somewhat different parameters.

Comment: Right, the plot is really nice then. I updated my original question once again to include the tweaks done in the book to obtain that plot using MathCAD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've adapted the code you showed and it seems to work okay with some modifications.

```
r:5;
b:2;
M:1000$
X(k):=r*cos(((k^2)/M)*%pi);
Y(k):=r*sin(((k^2)/M)*%pi);
Z(k):=b*k;
draw3d(nticks = 1000, parametric (X(k), Y(k), Z(k), k, 0, 45));
```

The major changes are that `foo_k := ...` in the MathCAD code is translated as `foo(k) := ...` in Maxima, and that the plotting variable is `k` (which is constructed to vary much more slowly than `t`) instead of `t` or `t(k)`.

Also I increased `nticks` by a lot, and cut out the mention of `t_k` since it doesn't come into the picture now.

By the way, I think if you say `draw3d` in wxMaxima, it will launch an external viewer instead of embedding an image in the notebook (with `wxdraw2d`, I think). You can drag with the mouse to rotate the plot in the external viewer, I think. That's helpful with 3-d plots. I could be mistaken about how to launch the viewer, since I don't use wxMaxima very much.

Comment: Thank you so much. The plot now looks very similar to what is presented in the book. I'm not 100% sure if it's exactly the same but it seems to be (the difference in axis adjustment may cause some visual discrepancy).